# UITableViewRowAction change backgroundcolor on press

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I created an instance of `UITableViewRowAction` in

```
 -(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and I have a handler block when this row action is triggered:

```
 handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
```

You have a row action parameter that can be used so you do not create retain cycles and you have an index path. I've tried setting the `backgroundColor` of that new row action like this:

```
 [action setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

But this did not change anything. I also tried `setNeedsDisplay` on the button object of the row action, but without any luck.

Any idea how I can change the `backgroundColor` while the row actions are still visible? Thanks

- xCoder

Comment: Post your implements of the  `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` here

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation of the same and it works well. It should solve your problem as well..

```
- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewRowAction *one = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:0 title:@"one" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {

        NSLog(@"my first action");
    }];

    UITableViewRowAction *two = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:1 title:@"two" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {

        NSLog(@"my second action");

    }];

    UITableViewRowAction *three = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:1 title:@"three" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {

        NSLog(@"my third action");
    }];

    one.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    two.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    three.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];

    return @[one, two, three];
}
```